Time dependence in Angle Variable
I came across a derivation of the action-angle variables $(J,w)$ under the following assumptions:

the generating function $W$ doesn't depend on time explicitly (therefore the new Hamiltonian $K$ is the original one in terms of the new canonical coordinates)

the original hamiltonian $H$ doesn't depend explicitly on time and

$K=K(J)$.


What the book argues is that $$w=\frac{\partial W}{\partial J}=w(q,J)$$ at the same time we also know that $$\dot w=\frac{\partial K}{\partial J}=v(J)$$ from which we get $$w=v(J)t+\beta.$$ Now my question is: How is it that $w$, being by assumption on $W$ only a function of $q$ and $J$, depends on time? My guess is that in the former case we use $q=q(t)$ and from that we can get $t=t(q)$ which would solve the issue. Is that right or is there something else I am missing?

Yes, Hamilton's characteristic function $W(q,J)$ may still have implicit time dependence, so the (solution to the) angle variable $w(t)$ can depend on time.

Ok perfect thanks!
